# How to evaluate the following integral faster?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics, timing

I have a problem with the time required for evaluating the multi-dimensional integral and would be grateful for any help in reducing this time.

First of all, there are some pre-definitions used in the integrand:

```
ZNNdata = {{137.31252947398974`, 
    0.494193722943723`}, {151.07724468801382`, 
    0.493964871933622`}, {166.210070006858`, 
    0.495370670995671`}, {182.86642559844006`, 
    0.49579568001443003`}, {201.2024534119898`, 
    0.495011047979798`}, {221.377972102387`, 
    0.49412833694083697`}, {243.57383822138488`, 
    0.4935071699134199`}, {267.9977576524213`, 
    0.49265715187590187`}, {294.86575262436986`, 
    0.49219944985569986`}, {324.43378931390953`, 
    0.49128404581529583`}, {356.9592501146247`, 
    0.4908590367965368`}, {392.75379088486216`, 
    0.4899436327561328`}, {432.129755180472`, 
    0.4894532377344878`}, {475.46680538656534`, 
    0.4883089826839827`}, {523.157378647326`, 
    0.48683779761904766`}, {575.6111556017011`, 
    0.48618393759018763`}, {633.3080803465944`, 
    0.4861185515873016`}, {696.7863459935301`, 
    0.4861185515873016`}, {766.6207340033653`, 
    0.48631470959595957`}, {843.4506039057271`, 
    0.4866089466089466`}, {927.9344919558865`, 
    0.4880474386724387`}, {1020.9108968956668`, 
    0.48879937770562776`}, {1123.2143577529516`, 
    0.48932246572871574`}, {1235.8217093251478`, 
    0.4888647637085137`}, {1359.7452959669813`, 
    0.4879493596681097`}, {1496.0385336816432`, 
    0.48791666666666667`}, {1645.9907203127123`, 
    0.48791666666666667`}, {1810.9934637015729`, 
    0.4876551226551227`}, {1992.581890401111`, 
    0.48687049062049065`}, {2192.359656282797`, 
    0.48628201659451664`}, {2412.1230864483514`, 
    0.4861185515873016`}, {2653.9344392877742`, 
    0.4857916215728716`}, {2920.1351722269155`, 
    0.4842877435064935`}, {3212.9327773914256`, 
    0.4835358044733045`}, {3535.0738121034665`, 
    0.48288194444444443`}, {3889.404289623066`, 
    0.48288194444444443`}, {4279.250316172906`, 
    0.48288194444444443`}, {4708.264636985841`, 
    0.4824242424242424`}, {5180.3334124453`, 
    0.4817703823953824`}, {5699.733624420286`, 
    0.4811165223665224`}, {6271.210905325155`, 
    0.4804626623376623`}, {6900.0061569502905`, 
    0.4797434163059163`}, {7591.966522899989`, 
    0.47866454725829727`}, {8353.566751343084`, 
    0.47689912518037525`}, {9191.296019225289`, 
    0.47582025613275614`}, {10113.307022834799`, 
    0.4741202200577201`}, {11127.447375985435`, 
    0.4731721230158731`}, {12243.456105895111`, 
    0.471897095959596`}, {13471.450037767512`, 
    0.4705239898989899`}, {14822.233166890233`, 
    0.46973935786435794`}, {16309.14912363083`, 
    0.46797393578643576`}, {17944.69618536043`, 
    0.46689506673881676`}, {19744.03981589582`, 
    0.46607774170274174`}, {21724.572153724694`, 
    0.46444309163059166`}, {23902.42460738394`, 
    0.46411616161616165`}, {26298.269512038867`, 
    0.4640834686147186`}, {28934.749935207263`, 
    0.46365845959595964`}, {31836.039102170667`, 
    0.46287382756132756`}, {35027.89505800395`, 
    0.4623180465367966`}, {38539.3293168312`, 
    0.46202380952380956`}, {42401.817212521164`, 
    0.46225266053391056`}, {46652.20047841108`, 
    0.46208919552669553`}, {51329.73006740882`, 
    0.46143533549783555`}, {56477.759523181565`, 
    0.4601603084415585`}, {62143.766450585805`, 
    0.4582641143578644`}, {68374.92575906859`, 
    0.4574794823232323`}, {75234.91394160192`, 
    0.45545251623376626`}, {82782.69110512076`, 
    0.4535563221500722`}, {91087.16877459173`, 
    0.45179090007215006`}, {100227.29483196106`, 
    0.4494304653679654`}, {110287.32153356668`, 
    0.44649463383838384`}, {121350.79899600163`, 
    0.4447619047619048`}, {133520.72158428284`, 
    0.4436176497113997`}, {146909.68099879692`, 
    0.4427022456709957`}, {161641.23527107167`, 
    0.4417868416305917`}, {177847.25693891916`, 
    0.4412310606060606`}, {195683.87436246622`, 
    0.43998872655122656`}, {215307.53670964515`, 
    0.43894255050505054`}, {236899.7763143353`, 
    0.43783098845598845`}, {260647.85248371153`, 
    0.43756944444444446`}, {286785.45447802567`, 
    0.4365886544011544`}, {315541.89457123907`, 
    0.4357713293650794`}, {347178.36333731207`, 
    0.43518285533910533`}, {381992.6517996495`, 
    0.4342347582972583`}, {420308.7062091489`, 
    0.43269818722943726`}, {462459.7358680408`, 
    0.43158008658008656`}, {508849.8262829067`, 
    0.42991928210678215`}, {559881.8588720871`, 
    0.4287357954545455`}, {616040.700211599`, 
    0.42721884018759015`}, {677856.0500886096`, 
    0.4248976370851371`}, {745874.9064749631`, 
    0.42255245911495914`}, {820731.4721854934`, 
    0.4198563762626263`}, {901842.5780358072`, 
    0.4159261326058201`}, {993846.5517565882`, 
    0.4118974985827665`}, {1.0937011897392983`*^6, 
    0.4068380230880231`}, {1.203531237380893`*^6, 
    0.4028821699134199`}, {1.3243344671259196`*^6, 
    0.3999071067821068`}, {1.457259090154337`*^6, 
    0.3969974296536796`}, {1.603552601552836`*^6, 
    0.39369543650793654`}, {1.76453990785395`*^6, 
    0.3902953643578643`}, {1.941678449692089`*^6, 
    0.3870260642135642`}, {2.136602578374088`*^6, 
    0.3837240710678211`}, {2.3510950428680493`*^6, 
    0.38042207792207794`}, {2.587120298621542`*^6, 
    0.3771200847763348`}, {2.846848038220949`*^6, 
    0.37375270562770563`}, {3.1326461054041293`*^6, 
    0.3704180194805195`}, {3.447101724963954`*^6, 
    0.3673121843434343`}, {3.792929966029318`*^6, 
    0.36538329725829727`}, {4.1734885009604455`*^6, 
    0.3632582521645022`}, {4.592048605336358`*^6, 
    0.3620486111111111`}, {5.0526004424795965`*^6, 
    0.36077358405483406`}, {5.559483624807911`*^6, 
    0.358910082972583`}, {6.117105856234256`*^6, 
    0.3574715909090909`}, {6.730620248722987`*^6, 
    0.35616387085137086`}, {7.405844472279785`*^6, 
    0.35430036976911977`}, {8.148911420292056`*^6, 
    0.3521426316738817`}, {8.966647907830844`*^6, 
    0.34969065656565657`}, {9.866471389832295`*^6, 
    0.34717329545454545`}, {1.0857038045209486`*^7, 
    0.34370783730158727`}, {1.1946465424215667`*^7, 
    0.3413866341991342`}, {1.3145005337203309`*^7, 
    0.33942505411255414`}, {1.446411608665069`*^7, 
    0.336940386002886`}, {1.5915129393080233`*^7, 
    0.3351422709235209`}, {1.751160691863829`*^7, 
    0.3334749278499278`}, {1.9267605474776793`*^7, 
    0.3325595238095238`}, {2.1199509698000796`*^7, 
    0.33184027777777775`}, {2.33243967000078`*^7, 
    0.33184027777777775`}, {2.5662267154727586`*^7, 
    0.33184027777777775`}, {2.823446899787937`*^7, 
    0.33184027777777775`}, {3.10644899293456`*^7, 
    0.33184027777777775`}, {3.4178412794899195`*^7, 
    0.33167681277056277`}, {3.760590846583662`*^7, 
    0.3306306367243867`}, {4.137566365409086`*^7, 
    0.3304017857142857`}, {4.552286380873794`*^7, 
    0.3304017857142857`}, {5.0086596883545265`*^7, 
    0.3300094696969697`}, {5.511010375322454`*^7, 
    0.3286690566378066`}, {6.0637963317992344`*^7, 
    0.32713248556998553`}, {6.671935835470581`*^7, 
    0.3259228445165945`}, {7.341262416403228`*^7, 
    0.32409203643578643`}, {8.077485121461858`*^7, 
    0.3229804743867244`}, {8.547240358570033`*^7, 
    0.3210515873015873`}};
(*Regeneration factor for proton*)
ZNN[Ep_] = Interpolation[ZNNdata, InterpolationOrder -> 1][Ep];
(*pp cross-section in mb in terms of invariant mass s*)
Z = 35.45;
B = 0.308;
Y1 = 42.53;
Y2 = 33.34;
s0 = 5.38^2;
s1 = 1;
eta1 = 0.458;
eta2 = 0.545;
S[Pp_, mp_] = 2*Pp*mp;
ECM2Elab[Elab_] = (Elab + 0.938)^2 - (Sqrt[Elab^2 - 0.938])^2;
Elabs[sqrts_] = Elab /. Solve[ECM2Elab[Elab] == sqrts^2, Elab][[1]];
sigmapp[Elab_] = (Z + B*Log[ECM2Elab[Elab]/s0]^2 + 
     Y1*(s1/ECM2Elab[Elab])^eta1 - Y2 (s1/ECM2Elab[Elab])^eta2)*10^-31;
(*Slant depth*)
h0 = 6400;
rho0 = 1.23(*13000/h0 *);
rhoAtm[h_] = rho0*Exp[-h/h0];
Rearth = 6400*10^3;
hlth[l_, costh_] = l*costh + l^2/(2*Rearth)*(1 - costh^2);
Xval[l_, costh_] = 
  Assuming[l > 0 && -1 < costh < 1, 
   Integrate[rhoAtm[hlth[L1, costh]], {L1, l, Infinity}]];
hlthexact[l_, costh_] = 
  Sqrt[Rearth^2 + l^2 + 2*l*Rearth*costh] - Rearth;
XvalExact[l_, costh_] := 
  NIntegrate[rhoAtm[hlth[L1, costh]], {L1, l, Infinity}];
XvalInt[l_, costh_] = 
  Interpolation[
    Flatten[ParallelTable[{10^l, costh, 
       Quiet[XvalExact[10^l, costh]]}, {l, Log10[10^-3], 
       Log10[200*10^3], 0.1}, {costh, -0.99, 0.99, 0.03}], {2, 1}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][l, costh];
ExperimentTransverseAreaInm2 = 10^6;
YearIns = 365*24*3600;
(*interaction thickness lN of nucleons N in air in kg/m^2*)
rhoAirTonAir = 1.6*10^-27;
lN[Ep_] = rhoAirTonAir/sigmapp[Ep];
LN[Ep_] = lN[Ep]/(1 - ZNN[Ep]);
```

Next, there is the integrand (a function PhiEpAtmosphereAbsorbed):

```
   (*Cosmic p flux in GeV^-1/sin(th)m^-2s^-1*)
PhiEp[Ep_] = (10^4*2*Pi)*
   Piecewise[{{1.7*Ep^-2.7, Ep < 5*10^6}, {174*Ep^-3, Ep >= 5*10^6}}];
(*p flux in atmosphere taking into account absorption and recreation*)


PhiEpAtmosphere[Ep_, l_, costh_] = 
  Exp[-XvalInt[l, costh]/LN[Ep]] PhiEp[Ep];
PhiEpAtmosphereAbsorbed[Ep_, l_, costh_] = 
  rhoAtm[hlth[l, costh]]/lN[Ep] PhiEpAtmosphere[Ep, l, costh];
```

**An example of the integral that I want to evaluate is**

```
NpExperiment := 
 YearIns*ExperimentTransverseAreaInm2*
  NIntegrate[
   PhiEpAtmosphereAbsorbed[ED, l, costh], {ED, 100, 10^7}, {l, 10^3, 
    80*10^3}, {costh, Cos[Pi/2], 1}, 
   Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]
```

`AbsoluteTiming[NpExperiment]` gives 10-20 s. Switching the method to MonteCarlo significantly decreases the integration time (down to ~1 s) but introduces a huge error depending on the Monte-Carlo points grid. Increasing the number of points improves accuracy but significantly slows down the evaluation.

Comment: You define `PhiEpAtmosphereAbsorbed[Ep_, l_, costh_] = rhoAtm[hlth[l, costh]]/lN[ED] PhiEpAtmosphere[ED, l, costh]`. Are you sure that's right? The value of `Ep` in that definition is not used, and instead the expression still contains undefined `ED`.

Comment: @MarcoB : thanks! Ep instead of ED.